# onclick for icon in RichFaces Calendar?

Tags: jsf, calendar, onclick, richfaces

Using RichFaces 3.3.x:

I want to trigger some javascript code of ours when the user clicks on the calendar icon.

it works fine for the text field itself using

```
oninputclick="ourFunction();"
```

and i was expecting it to be some similar attribute for the button (icon), but i cant find it.
Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Couldn't you bind the function to the click-event in pure Javascript? Like `jQuery.click()` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an onexpand attribute for the rich:calendar component:

> The client-side script method to be called before the calendar popup
>   is opened